# C#: How to parse HttpWebResponse object?

Tags: c#

I can explain this question better in terms of code and example. This is my code so far:

```
url = "x";

// create the request
req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
req.ClientCertificates.Add(Program.GetCert(thumbprint));
result = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

using (Stream data = result.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (data != null)
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(data);
        json = tr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

This is the output of the code:

> {   "field1":"blah","field2":[
>       {
>         "Id":"1","Name":"Jon"
>       },{
>         "Id":"2","Name":"Mark"}] }

What I want to do-->
Access field2 of that json and iterate through ids and names (I don't care about field1 at all). How can I do that? Has this got anything to do with serialization?

Comment: Just use a JSON deserializer - ideally, into a typed object, but you can also use dictionaries or `dynamic` if you're so inclined.

Comment: Tips: If you have complex objects in json you could use http://json2csharp.com/ to write the objects that you deserialize to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible solution is -

```
        var o = (JArray)(JObject.Parse(json)["field2"]);
        foreach (JToken token in o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(token["Id"]);
            Console.WriteLine(token["Name"]);
        }
```

Alternatively, you could create strongly typed C# objects and access them as a list -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json).field2;// list - count = 2
    }

public class Field2
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public List<Field2> field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DataContractJsonSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with suitable DataContract classes ([Using Data Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), to deserialize your JSON data to objects.

Then you can iterate your way through the data.

Answer (score 1):

First install Json.NET and try something like:

```
 dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(json);
 var field2 = (JArray)stuff["field2"];

 var field2Dict = field2.ToDictionary(k => (string)k["Id"], x => (string)x["Name"]);
 foreach (var item in field2Dict)
 {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Id: {0}  Nam: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
 }
```